# stopwatch clear variable javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey all I'm extremely unfamiliar in using javascript... I just need help clearing the time (this should stop the time then clear it) in my script. See:  function clear() thanks :) if you have any suggestions in merging the stop\start button into one function that'd be appreciated too. thank you again!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var clsStopwatch = function () {

var startAt = 0;
var lapTime = 0;

var now = function () {
    return (new Date()).getTime();
};

this.start = function () {
    startAt = startAt ? startAt : now();
};

this.stop = function () {
lapTime = startAt ? lapTime + now() - startAt : lapTime;
startAt = 0;
};

this.time = function () {
    return lapTime + (startAt ? now() - startAt : 0);
};
};

var x = new clsStopwatch();
var $time;
var clocktimer;

function pad(num, size) {
var s = "0000" + num;
return s.substr(s.length - size);
}

function formatTime(time) {
var h = m = s = ms = 0;
var newTime = '';

m = Math.floor(time / (60 * 1000));
time = time % (60 * 1000);
s = Math.floor(time / 1000);
ms = time % 1000;

newTime = pad(m, 2) + ':' + pad(s, 2) + ':' + pad(ms, 2);
return newTime;
}

function show() {
$time = document.getElementById('time');
update();
}

function update() {
$time.innerHTML = formatTime(x.time());
}

function start() {
clocktimer = setInterval("update()", 1);
x.start();
}

function stop() {
x.stop();
document.getElementById('counter').value = formatTime(x.time());
clearInterval(clocktimer);
}

function clear() {
x.stop();
????????? this is the function i need help on

}
 </script>
```

html:

```
<body onload="show();">

<form action="submit.php" method="post"/>

Time: <span id="time"></span><br/>
<!--<input type="text" name-"time">-->
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start();">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop();">
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clear();">
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="stop();">
<br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, forgot to put `show()` in the `start()` function

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/64gFm/

Change the `clear()` function to `clearWatch()` as clear is an inbult function 
New Updated Js Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/64gFm/1/

```
function clearWatch() {
    x.stop();
    x.clear();
    clearInterval(clocktimer);
    update();
}
```

Hope, it may help you. Have anice day. :)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity it's going to be submitted to php via a form. I need help Clearing (Stop+Clear) the Timer. function clear() {

Comment: code is updated and check the updated fiddle. tick the answer as correct. :)